# jQuery document.ready() doesn't work with Require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, document-ready, domready

I am calling Require.js from right before the closing body tag:

```
    <script data-main="assets/scripts/src/main.js" src="assets/scripts/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is what my `main.js` contains:

```
requirejs.config({
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(), // override browser cache
});

require(['views/appView'], function (App) {
    App.initialize(); // this is just to test the module is actually loading
});
```

And appView.js contains:

```
define([
    'modernizr',
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'common', // this module has about 4 other dependencies too
    'dust',
    'routers/main',
    'views/main'
], function (Modernizr, $, _, Backbone, Common, dust, router, mainView) {
    // This is supposed to load, even if jQuery loads after the DOM ready event
    $(document).on('ready', function () {
        console.log("I don't want to play nice");
    });

    return {
        initialize: function () {
            console.log("Init");
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, this: `console.log("I don't want to play nice");` does not happen *at all*.

This is how my network timeline looks in Chrome Dev Tools. As you can see, the DOM ready event fires way before jQuery loads - but AFAIK, jQuery knows how to handle this! So I am lost.
[image]

Comment: The answer to your issue aside, calling require.js just before the closing body tag defeats the point of asynchronous loading entirely. The require.js file itself is loaded sequentially - so if you call it at the end of your document then the modules you've defined wont start loading (albeit asynchronously) until after the content ... the whole purpose of requireJS and asynchronous loading is that you can call scripts first in the head on a dedicated simultaneous browser thread so they load whilst the content does without slowing it down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("I don't want to play nice");
});
```

***`$(document).on("ready", handler)`, deprecated as of jQuery 1.8***
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Note the problem isn't that the `.on("ready"` version is deprecated (though it is and you shouldn't use it), it's that the `.on("ready"` version doesn't call the handler if it is bound after the ready event happens.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal that's not true, you can call `$(document).ready` after it has already fired, and the function you pass will be called instantly.

Comment: Yes, as pilau says, `.ready()` is a special case where the handler will be called even if the event had already happened. (Obviously this doesn't apply to other events like clicks or whatever.)

Answer (score 2):

Given that RequireJS is used to load only the modules needed for a specific page, developers may not want to load the entire jQuery library on some pages just for its `$(document).ready(function(){})` callback.  Alternatively, use RequireJS' [domReady](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload) in appView.js:

```
define([
    'domReady',
    'modernizr',
    'etc'
], function (domReady, Modernizr, etc) {
    domReady(function () {
        console.log("I'll play nice");
    });
});
```

or add an `!` on the `domReady` define to avoid nested callbacks:

```
define([
    'domReady!',
    'modernizr',
    'etc'
], function (domReady, Modernizr, etc) {
    console.log("I'll also play nice");
});
```